# Layout Details Not Being Published

Tags: publishing

I have an item with 6 controls in the layout details. When I publish, only 1  control in the layout details is being published. I want all the layout details controls to be published, but I cannot figure out why the other 5 controls are not being published to the web database. All of the layouts and templates have been verified to exist in the web database. I have tried publishing multiple times and a successful publish is always indicated.

We are using Sitecore 7.5.

**Publish Settings:**

[image]

**Master Database:**

[image]

**Web Database (After Publish):**

[image]

**Here is some of the logging information:**

```
7436 16:56:54 INFO  [Publishing]: Starting to process 1 publishing options
7436 16:56:54 INFO  [PublishOptions]: root:{C0DBB99F-72DA-4B56-A0AF-9A7DE9BEC070}, language:en, targets:Internet, database:web, mode:SingleItem, smart:True children:True, related:True
7888 16:56:54 WARN  DeepItemPublish detected. PublishContext was overridden with DisableDatabaseCaches=True.
7888 16:56:54 INFO  Starting [Publishing] - ProcessQueue
7888 17:02:58 INFO  Finished [Publishing] - ProcessQueue in 364401 ms
7888 17:02:58 INFO  Publish Mode : SingleItem
7888 17:02:59 INFO  Created : 0
7888 17:02:59 INFO  Updated : 29
7888 17:02:59 INFO  Deleted : 1
7888 17:02:59 INFO  Skipped : 775318
4820 17:04:13 INFO  [Publishing]: Starting to process 1 publishing options
4820 17:04:13 INFO  [PublishOptions]: root:{5FF2C731-384D-4420-801C-CE7DD046AACC}, language:en, targets:Internet, database:web, mode:SingleItem, smart:False children:True, related:True
7412 17:04:13 WARN  DeepItemPublish detected. PublishContext was overridden with DisableDatabaseCaches=True.
7412 17:04:13 INFO  Starting [Publishing] - ProcessQueue
7412 17:05:28 INFO  Finished [Publishing] - ProcessQueue in 74978 ms
7412 17:05:28 INFO  Publish Mode : SingleItem
7412 17:05:28 INFO  Created : 0
7412 17:05:28 INFO  Updated : 794
7412 17:05:28 INFO  Deleted : 0
7412 17:05:28 INFO  Skipped : 0
```

**Raw Values for Renderings on Master:**

```
<r xmlns:p="p" xmlns:s="s" p:p="1">

<d id="{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}">   the default layout

<r uid="{618896CE-55C4-44C4-B4DF-C6718361821E}">  not found
<p:d />
</r>      

<r uid="{F87FA886-A693-49F2-B989-806830B9379B}"  not found

p:before="r[@uid='{CD25EEB7-729D-4EB2-9423-99EF7DEA7CE0}']" not found

s:id="{75C72E54-0D18-4BED-877B-8BE79992D12D}" this is found Channel Partner Listing

s:ph="Inner Content" />
</d>

<d id="{207131FA-F6B2-4488-BCB3-3BF70100B9B8}">  app center placeholder

<r uid="{9D07FE7B-AB06-496F-AF3B-F02D185E289C}"> not found

<p:d />

</r>

<r uid="{ED82E2E5-E7E0-4F43-A875-DA36D3DB9509}" not found

p:before="r[@uid='{09539080-F041-4C45-95D3-99F2B070BE40}']" not found


s:id="{043679EC-6A0E-4BE1-9CEB-2A09AFDC5844}" mobile channel partner listing

s:ph="Inner Content" />

</d>
</r>
```

Comment: have you published Layouts and templates to web ?? can you try publishing /Layouts & /templates separately ?

Comment: They should be there, all the other pages that use them work fine. I will double check.

Comment: Yeah, they are there on the web database.

Comment: @ADH Do you have any exceptions, errors or warnings related to publishing? I would also try to republish the item instead of smart publish.

Comment: No errors. I could check the log files though.

Comment: @ADH I would also try to republish the item instead of smart publish.

Comment: I just tried that. No change.

Comment: Is there a workflow setup for publishing? Are all items in final state if so? Publish mode was SingleItem. So, it could be that your renderings are in a parent folder which is not yet published. Same can go for templates also.

Comment: Are you able to change other fields on the item? Are they successfully published. Presentation details are fields like any other field on that context item. They are just represented by XML and rendered differently in the Content Editor.

If other fields are not published either then it's a problem with the context item itself. I have seen this before if the parent item have a different ID in the master database than in the web database. If that is the case, you are trying to publish an orphan item and that will be ignored. Just a guess... :)

Comment: The workflow stuff seems okay. Stuff is marked as done. I'm not sure how that would matter on the stuff that is already on the web database.

Comment: Yes, I am able to change other fields and those changes are being published.

Comment: Try and click View and check "Raw Values" and compare the raw values in master and web for the layout fields. If they are different, try and copy/paste the master database values in the web database values to see if that changes anything. That will obviously not fix the publishing problem but it might lead to an understanding of what is going on.

Comment: Are any of the affected items clones? See https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/490254

Comment: @ADH Did you manage to solve the issue? If not, have you tried Jonas's suggestion?

Comment: No, this issue is not solved. My best guess is it is related to workflows, but I am not sure yet. I tried raw values, but nothing seemed out of place.

Comment: @JonasAgertoft I am looking at the raw values for the rendering field and trying to search for the GUIDs. Most of the items are not being found. Does that make sense? Shouldn't all the GUIDs be found?

Comment: @scFootsteps Can you please put this as an answer so I can mark it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please double check that "Never publish" field of "Layout" is unchecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you published Layouts and templates to web? 
Can you try publishing /Layouts & /templates separately.

When you don't have related layout items published to web database, page item's presentation details will not show in Sitecore Content Editor (UI tool) interfaces in web. But, when you check raw values of that field, you can see the reference values in the field.

When you publish the Layout items, page item's presentation details will start to appear in content editor.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1025)

Comment: i have posted this as an comment earlier. Author request to post it as an answer to accept it.

Comment: Ok, didn't see that one between the flood of comments.. Maybe try to rephrase your answer to make it look less of a comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Bug with item clones

If any of the involved items are virtual items, then what you're seeing is a known defect. See the following Knowledge Base article for a fix:

http://kb.sitecore.net/articles/490254

## Unpublished items

This sometimes happens due to the fact that some of the related items (such as rendering definitions, layout definitions, templates, placeholder settings, etc.) don't exist in the language you're publishing in.

#### Fixes

There are 2 ways to fix this:

- Add English versions of those items unavailable in English
- Or perform the publish in all languages

#### Under the hood

What I believe happens: the value of the `__Layout` field does get published. This field only contains IDs of the layout(s) and renderings, as well as placeholder keys. When you open the item's Presentaion Details dialog, Sitecore will try to get the items that represent the layout definition and rendering definitions. It cannot find them (as they haven't been published), so it has no way of showing and using them.

Comment: I tried checking off all the languages,but nothing changed on the web database.

Comment: @ADH Can you try to publish `/layouts` and `/templates` in all languages as well? With subitems, of course.

Comment: I have not used the Clone option for any of my items.

Answer (score 1):

@ADH as a response to your comment on my previous suggestion...

The raw values in the rendering field in the web database will show item ID's of all related renderings and datasources. In later versions of Sitecore you would have been able to publish the item and checking "publish related items". Since you don't have that option I would write down all those ID's in that field, go back to the master database and identify the items with these ID's. Publish all of them one by one and see if they appear in the web database. Once all related items are published you should be able to see the rendering on your page.

Comment: 6 of the item ids are not found. This is confusing because the page works correctly in preview mode.

Comment: Preview mode is looking at your master database and not your web database. If preview mode was looking at your web database the items would already be live 

Comment: See my raw values above. They are not found on the master database.

Comment: Are you saying that you can see the renderings in preview mode and that all looks fine but searching for the rendering ID's and datasource ID's that make up the rendering are not in your database? That doesn't make sense... 

Comment: That is exactly what I am saying. And I agree it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I would try to remove the renderings and set them up again one by one again. See if the rendering field references the same ID in the raw values as your original page...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49791/discussion-between-adh-and-jonas-agertoft).